# MariaDB case-sensitivity

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am brand new to MySQL and MariaDB.  I have worked many years in the past with Oracle and recently gave a try to HSQLDB before trying MariaDB last week-end.  It turns out to be a painfull experience.  I don't mention the lack of hierarchical queries or CTE's and the error messages...  After all, it is a free product.

But one thing I completely fail to understand is why a statement can fail when I write the reserved words in uppercase and then run when written in lowercase.  For instance something stupid like `DROP TABLE` may fail.  I write 'may' because the behaviour is not consistent.  It can happen when I connect to the server using SSH and the CLI from an Ubuntu 14.04 machine.  It can happen from MySQL Workbench.  But the same command when I connect through SSH from an OS X machine and use the CLI may run !  It is the case with the statement below (look at the failure in uppercase from Ubuntu, the same ran from OS X).  I am lost.  Any hint ?

Marc

```
MariaDB [ws]> select date_add('2014-01-01 00:00:00', interval 30 minute);
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| date_add('2014-01-01 00:00:00', interval 30 minute) |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| 2014-01-01 00:30:00                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [ws]> SELECT DATE_ADD('2014-01-01 00:00:00', INTERVAL 30 MINUTE);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT DATE_ADD('2014-01-01 00:00:00', INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It may complaining about whatever came immediately before 'SELECT', not about the case.

```
mysql> select date_add('2014-01-01 00:00:00', interval 30 minute);
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| date_add('2014-01-01 00:00:00', interval 30 minute) |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| 2014-01-01 00:30:00                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT DATE_ADD('2014-01-01 00:00:00', INTERVAL 30 MINUTE);
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| DATE_ADD('2014-01-01 00:00:00', INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| 2014-01-01 00:30:00                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```